# is it possible to edit published visual studio asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications

I have published a asp.net website using visual studio. However, I wish to make changes to a web page but I found out that the published site only have .aspx extension files and there is no code-behind .vb file which is like development.

Is there any way for me to edit without republish again? Or can I convert the published website back to original as I do not have any backup for the published files.

Answer (score 0):

Download all the files from the server and use something like a [reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) to get the source code from the binary/bin folder.

And for future always use a source control, I use dropbox.

Comment: DropBox **is not a source control!!** Their EULA allows the dropbox employees to read your files. That is not something you want on a source control server.

Comment: thanks for the reply. or if i have one of the source file, can i simply compiled and overwrite 1 of the file? I have saw the folder inside got dll, and .compiled file but i'm not sure how it works.

Comment: Your .cs files are converted into binary and stored in the bin folder as binary. A reflector can be used to extract the code from the binary files produced. Have a look at the reflector you will find out that its very useful in this scenario.

Comment: @FilipEkberg, didn't knew that. Used dropbox because of the simplicity and minimal learning time. I am under the impression source controls cost money and have a substantial learning curve.

Comment: ok i will give reflector a try. But is it possible for me just to update 1 web page instead of republished the whole site?

Comment: You can just rebuild the project and then just update any of the dlls that have changed.

Answer (score 0):

The dll's are just the compiled assemblies of your source code.  You can manually update any of the dll's that are updated without going through the whole publishing process again.  You may need to make a minor change to your web config file after updating the dlls so as to trigger IIS to reload the latest dlls.

Answer (score 0):

you can change

```
<%@ page language="VB" autoeventwireup="false" inherits="test, App_Web_olnjngph" culture="bg-BG" uiculture="bg-BG" %>
```

with

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="test.aspx.vb" Inherits="test"  Culture="bg-BG" UICulture="bg-BG" %>
```

and edit source code after that inside file **`test.aspx.vb`**

Comment: Can you format this a little better? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for formatting help.