# Copying live / deployed c# website into Visual Studio Dev Environment

Tags: c#, visual-studio, umbraco

What are the best steps to take when copying an c# live website from the server into a development environment in Visual Studio (to create a solution, etc. in VS)?

Is it possible?

I'm trying to copy an umbraco website from the server and run it in a development environment in Visual Studio by creating a blank new project in Visual Studio. Will the nuget packages, etc. that are installed on the website be lost when copying from the web server?

I realize I will also have to copy the database over.

Comment: You might find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074462/is-it-possible-to-edit-published-visual-studio-asp-net-website useful - its the same question but for VB.NET. Seems like you can use a reflector to view the compiled DLLS and edit them

Comment: @Bassie Thanks. Do you know if this is an absolute way to duplicate the development project? I ask b/c the dev project became corrupt, and rather than working backwards I rather just copy the working server version. I am worried that things like NUGET packages will not be translated backwards with the reflector.

Comment: I'm not sure what will happen with those, but aren't nuget packages mainly stored as dlls? So you can just copy those dlls directly and you don't need to reflect them. If all else fails you can just re-install any required nuget packages